# Create automatically skype group url link

Tags: skype

Is there any way to create automatically skype group url link with php or jQuery? (or other languages)

Like this

> https://join.skype.com/xXxxXXxxxXXX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
skype:skype.test.user.1;skype.test.user.2;skype.test.user.3?call
```

I think [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745882.aspx) can help you.